# Error adding update trigger to select columns in a table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to add a trigger, when a table is updated (except for two columns in that table), it updates another table. The query I used is given below:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON town_1a2b3c4d
BEGIN
    IF NOT UPDATE (is_killed) AND NOT UPDATE (is_executed)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE town_details SET game_index = game_index + 1 WHERE town_id = '1a2b3c4d';
        END;
END;
```

But it gives me this error:

**MySQL said**

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
>       IF NOT UPDATE (is_killed) AND NOT UPDATE (is_executed)
>           BEGIN...' at line 3

Comment: Try without `AS` and terminate the statements with `;`.

Comment: @stickybit which statements should I terminate?

Comment: All of the statements.

Comment: `FOR EACH ROW` is lost. `AS` is errorneous. Maybe it is a time to look at User Manual? server will never accept the syntax which you come up for it.

Comment: @stickybit I updated the question, same error.

Comment: IF NOT UPDATE (is_killed) AND NOT UPDATE (is_executed) - is not valid mysql syntax specifically UPDATE which cannot be used in this context. You can test the NEW. values

Comment: [CREATE TRIGGER syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) - study.

Comment: @P.Salmon can you write an answer with the trigger that i'm trying to achieve?

Comment: You have to test every NEW. column against the OLD. column to see if towndetails should be updated. And I would be inclined to do this in an AFTER trigger rather than a BEFORE where you are assuming that the update to  town_1a2b3c4d will be successful

Comment: @P.Salmon I don't know how to do that.